# Weired Behavior of Round function in MSSQL Database for Real column only

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I found weird or strange behavior of Round function in MSSQL for real column type. I have tested this issue in Azure SQL DB and SQL Server 2012

> Why @number=201604.125 Return 201604.1 ?
>
> Why round(1.12345,10) Return 1.1234500408 ?

```
-- For Float column it working as expected
-- Declare @number as float,@number1 as float;
    Declare @number as real,@number1 as real;
set @number=201604.125;
set @number1=1.12345;
select @number as Realcolumn_Original
,round(@number,2) as Realcolumn_ROUND_2
,round(@number,3) as Realcolumn_ROUND_3
, @number1 as Realcolumn1_Original

,round(@number1,6) as Realcolumn1_ROUND_6
,round(@number1,7) as Realcolumn1_ROUND_7
,round(@number1,8) as Realcolumn1_ROUND_8
,round(@number1,9) as Realcolumn1_ROUND_9
,round(@number1,10) as Realcolumn1_ROUND_10
```

Output for real column type
[image]

Comment: What is it you're questioning? What results were in expecting instead? You don't state this, Also, please don't post code, or results, as a image like that. Use `text`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ***suspect*** what you are asking here is why does:

```
DECLARE @n real = 201604.125;
SELECT @n;
```

Return `201604.1`?

First point of call for things like this should be the documentation: Let's start with [float and real (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Firstly we note that:

> The ISO synonym for `real` is `float(24)`.

If we then look further down:

> float [ (n) ] Where n is the number of bits that are used to store the
>   mantissa of the float number in scientific notation and, therefore,
>   dictates the precision and storage size. If n is specified, it must be
>   a value between 1 and 53. The default value of n is 53. n value
>
> `Precision     Storage   size`
>
> `1-24          7 digits  4 bytes`

So, now we know that a `real` (aka a `float(24)`) has precision of 7. `201604.125` has a precision of 9, that's 2 too many; so off come that 2 and 5 in the return value.

Now, [ROUND (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). That states:

> Returns a numeric value, rounded to the specified length or precision.

When using `real`/`float` those digits aren't actually lost, as such, due to the floating point. When you use `ROUND`, you are specifically stating "I want this many decimal places". This is why you can then see the `.13` and the `.125`, as you have specifically asked for those. When you just returned the value of `@number` it had a precision of 7, due to being a `real`, so `201604.1` was the value returned.